# How to send http get with access token in java

Tags: java, http, get, access-token

I received a valid token from the server, and now I want to send a GET request with the token.

my libary:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.Consts;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

my code:

```
//My site is set as insecure, so I set the following setting
            TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

            SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                    .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                    .build();
            
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

but i get eror:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method GET must not have a request body.
```

I am new to HTTP calls,
And I would be happy for help and a solution.

Comment: please attach more lines from the stacktrace. Please include the imports which you are using and which version of libriaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method GET must not have a request body.
```

This error means in your request can't send body with **get** method, you need to use **post** method for sending body with data. With **get** you can only take data.

Please read this page about Get VS Post methods, for introducing to get and post methods.
https://www.javatpoint.com/get-vs-post

```
URL url = new URL("// Your web request");
    
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); // if need spesify request type
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer TOKEN HERE");
    
//e.g. bearer token=token is here

//conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request can't send body with get, so you can turn the request into something like this:

request.method("GET", null)

The request GET is now sending null, so you don't have to change it to POST anymore.

I recommend you to use postman before go into real code, you can easily test things there, and if this didn't help try to use the lib okhttp/okio it should fit on your code.

See ya